# How to convert this string: \n53,56 €\n into a number ? - Python Web Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to convert this string: `\n53,56 €\n` into a number with Python but I haven't been able to find a solution.

I am using `BeautifulSoup (bs4)` to get information from a website. This below is part of the `HTML` code with the string that I want to convert:

```
<span class="list-item-formatted-price" itemprop="price" content="53.56">
 <b>53,
   <sup>56
  </sup> €
 </b>
</span>
```

I tried many things including replacing the \n characters with the function below but it isn't working:

```
tyre_price = tyre_box.find('span',class_ = 'list-item-formatted-price').text.replace('\\n','')
price = float(tyre_price)
```

My goal is to convert the price from this string `\n53,56 €\n` into a number. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """
<span class="list-item-formatted-price" itemprop="price" content="53.56">
 <b>53,
   <sup>56
  </sup> €
 </b>
</span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

price = soup.select_one(".list-item-formatted-price").get_text(strip=True)

# convert to float
price = float(price.replace("€", "").replace(",", "."))
print(price)
```

Prints:

```
53.56
```

---

Or:

```py
price = float(soup.select_one(".list-item-formatted-price")["content"])
print(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

1st method as you can see from html content is ther which has value in it so you can grab it by following method

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""<span class="list-item-formatted-price" itemprop="price" content="53.56">
 <b>53,
   <sup>56
  </sup> €
 </b>
</span>"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
span=soup.find("span",attrs={"class":"list-item-formatted-price"})
data=span.get("content")
data=float(data)
```

2nd method is bit complex because you need to remove extra `\n` by `strip` method than there is `,` so replace with `.` and also space should not there and finally convert into `list`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
span=soup.find("span",attrs={"class":"list-item-formatted-price"})
lst1=span.text.strip("\n").replace(",",".").replace(" ","").split("\n")
data=float("".join(lst1[:2]))
```

Output from both:

```
53.56
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_content = """<span class="list-item-formatted-price" itemprop="price" content="53.56">
  <b>53,
     <sup>56
     </sup> €
  </b>
 </span>"""
tyre_box = BeautifulSoup(html_content)
text = tyre_box.find('span',class_ = 'list-item-formatted-price').text.replace('\\n','')
number = float("".join(text.split()).replace(',', '.').replace('€', ''))
```